Is there a better word for 'anonymity' here?
This is the sentence:

The Festival was the reason he had chosen this place to enter the country, the safety and 'anonymity' it provided would make his further travels much smoother.

Some context:
The character is from outsider and needs to travel all the way across the country. While outsiders are always welcome, they face a level of scrutiny at every town they visit which might cause problems for him. So he enters during the festival when there are many tourists, thus making him stand out less and he faces a lower level of scrutiny.
Safety here refers to safety on the road from monsters and bandits, so that part is irrelevant.
By anonymity what I wish to convey is that people, of small towns, will be more tolerant of him, an outsider. Not to say they generally aren't, they are fine with outsider, but there's scrutiny which is relaxed to levels comfortable for the character.
'Anonymity' here gives more of an impression of complete invisibility instead of tolerance, thereby failing to convey my meaning.
What other word or mixed word or phrase could I use here, such that I don't need to change the entire sentence? The sentence flows really well with the surrounding paragraphs and I would prefer not to scrap it if possible.

Seems reasonable, and you don't need quotes if by 'anonymity" you mean anonymity. Or maybe you meant small-town friendliness.

I think you mean less conspicuous, by blending in with all the tourists, being part of a horde, so not standing out, sort of anonymous in that way.

@HippoSawrUs YES, inconspicuousness, that's what I want to convey. Thanks putting it succinctly.

@HippoSawrUs Nice!

If you'd accommodate two words, 'seamless[ly] blending' seems appropriate. I'd make this an 'answer' if you added the < phrase request > and < idiom request > tags.

YW, the noun is a bit of a mouthful, but something along those lines…

Hospitality may be the word you’re looking for. The natives or locals welcome outsiders, whom they recognize. Thus, outsiders are not in fact anonymous.
See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenia_(Greek) for hospitality and its obligations in ancient Greece.

Untraceability or untrackability seems appropriate, but it unwieldy.
Rewording slightly:

The Festival was the reason he had chosen this place to enter the
country, the increased number of foreigners would make his own movements untraceable.


Now that the poster has made allowance for phrases as well (previously it's only SWR), I propose lost in the shuffle.

Failing to stand out among others. This metaphoric term alludes to mixing playing cards before dealing them. [c. 1900]

In that huge economics class Jane's afraid she'll get lost in the shuffle .
[Dictionary.com]

You could say

The Festival was the reason he had chosen this place to enter the country, the safety and blending in it provided would make his further travels much smoother.

Blend in means

to look like things nearby; to look like one belongs with a particular group

The fish settles on the sandy ocean bottom where it blends in perfectly. (M-W)



Nice suggestion. "The safety and the occasion for blending in it provided...", perhaps. It sounds a bit off with just ...the blending in it provided.

The idea of a city as providing anonymity is a common one, so that's probably as good a word as any. Some examples follow.
In 2017, the BBC quoted Peter Swire, professor of law and ethics at Georgia Institute of Technology:

Anonymity didn’t exist in small towns in the days of yore ... To some extent, urban living created anonymity.

The idea probably goes back to the great 19th century urban novelists like Dickens and Dostoevsky. Rosa Inocencio Smith in an essay "Paranoid Narcissism: What Dostoevsky Knew About the Internet" wrote about Dostoevsky's The Double:

Dostoevsky, writing in 1846 ... saw people lonely and paranoid and vain, isolated and beset by their imaginary selves, and he wondered, perhaps, over human beings’ chances for connection. At the time, societies across Europe were becoming increasingly urbanized, and the crowded, anonymous life of the city increased each person’s encounters with others

You can find it discussed theoretically as far back as the 1950s e.g.
"Urbanism, Anonymity, and Status Symbolism", William H. Form and Gregory P. Stone, American Journal of Sociology, Vol. 62, No. 5 (Mar., 1957), pp. 504-514 (11 pages)
